# Known most part of the src string,is it possible that a MD5 string can be decrypted?

Tags: md5

thank you,the good man who walk into my question.

I've got a problem that confused me for days.I have a MD5 string(16 bits)"4A09FA2815DA056F" and some candidate parts of the source string,they are "INIT","30000279577201","B4B3B4EBC12337FF46962DFC0E247324","86BECC17EAB9062CC50CEF6CD3F9A99E","381C7E40FF6CDC7460EFCB5EEABAC1B7","56C2C4DEDE00AF7D","2579051","0000000000","20130606125514","460026893893141","865062011362641","0E96A5DC561C7C30" ,if the one is used,it is linked with others by charactor "#",for example，"INIT#20130606125514#2579051#0000000000#460026893893141#865062011362641#30000279577201"

I have make a great effort to sovle it(arrange them to a new string and get the MD5 result)but failed,i think there may be a little part that I do not know.If given the above prerequisites,is the decrypt work easier than normal brute force decrypting?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind hashing is, that it can not be reversed. That means, you can only try be brute force, but knowing parts of the string will help.

If you know, in what order the parts are, and the maximum length of the original string, brute force should not take too long.

Comment: tks a lot,my problem is even parts of the string are given,i still do not know how to deal with it.